# How to combine window location and onclick properly?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, onclick

EDIT: I have a form, the user can input his/her personal basic information. After the user submit the form, he/she will redirect to another page and receive an email.

Now, I have two a JS (from Google Analytic tracking event) code to track the no. of click. I placed this code in input html tag, but after I clicked the input submit, the page is not redirecting to another page.

I tried to this, but it's not working

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Submit', 'Click', 'Fill up Form', '0');">
```

PHP snippet of redirecting and receiving an email

```
if (mail($mail_to, $subject, $message_body, $header)){
            ob_start();
            header('Location: /thank-you/');
            exit();
        } else{
            echo "Error";
        }
```

Comment: use php header location

Comment: Why do you think echoing an anchor element would cause a redirect? The user would have to click the anchor. Also, your `onclick` attribute won't work because of all the single quotes.

Comment: @nnnnnn, i tried to do this, <a onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Submit', 'Click', 'Fill up Form', '0');" href='/thank-you/'/><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"value="Submit"></a> but still not working :(